# Disable screen window in sipp

Tags: sip, asterisk

When we execute the sipp tool that time it is showing the different types of screen and statistics for calls.
Is it possible to disable the screens and statistics while executing the sipp tool? Because I used to get that screen and statistics in a text file after calls are executed. So I don't want that screen window while executing the sipp tool.So that I'm asking is there any way to do it?. If anyone know about this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the option that runs SIPp in background mode.

```
   -bg              : Launch SIPp in background mode.
```